# Round/Ceil part numbers to match Total values

Tags: javascript, mysql, math

so this is a bit bizarre question, which i lack the words to search for (English is not my native language).

i have `double` values coming from an MySQL db.
i display those values in a table, but need to show values as millions and percentage.

Example data:

`value1: 16658807.49`

`value2: 94182053.40718205`

`value3: 1005668.7204374762`

`value4: 422893.84666449524`

those values sum up to 112269423.46428402144.
my `toMillions` function:

```
function toMillions(num, decimalPlaces) {
    var str;
    decimalPlaces = decimalPlaces || 0;
    num = +num;
    var factor = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    str = Math.floor(num / (1000000 / factor)) / factor;
    return str;
}
```

`toMillions(112269423.46428402144,0)` = `112`
which is not bad.

The actual issue comes to play when i try to calculate the percentage of each:

`(value1 / 112269423.46428402144)*100` = `14.838240881587516953758075138633`

`(value2 / 112269423.46428402144)*100` = `83.889317768825935717434356973035`

`(value3 / 112269423.46428402144)*100` = `0.8957636811570578380232989593602`

`(value4 / 112269423.46428402144)*100` = `0.37667766842948949078426892897153`

but, i need to display the percentage as integer (dropping the decimal point).
if i do so using `Math.ceil` or `Math.round`, the total percentage value does not add up to 100%

the same goes for the Millions representation.

any help?

Comment: If you are only displaying the data then why not use the inbuilt database functions i.e. round() , truncate() etc. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-functions.html

Comment: This is financial data and should be as accurate as possible.
also, the same data is used in different parts of the system where it need to be the exact value.

Comment: Having one system i.e. the database to manipulate the data is better than using two systems mySQL and JavaScript.

Comment: @jeff - i agree, but MySQL double has rounding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand your question now. Hopefully this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yq6ycyhr/) answers it. I took the liberty of rounding each percentage to 10 decimal places. Now, when they are added, they equal 100. The rounding process itself is essential, as some (or all?) of  those percentages are repeating decimals, and JavaScript automatically cuts them off and rounds. They will never be 100% accurate. The question is, how close is close enough?

JS:

```
function round_number(num, dec) {
    return Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
}

var v1 = 16658807.49;
var v2 = 94182053.40718205;
var v3 = 1005668.7204374762;
var v4 = 422893.84666449524;
var vals = [v1,v2,v3,v4];
var tot = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += (tot+'<br/>');
for (var v in vals) {
    vals[v] = (vals[v] / tot) * 100;
    vals[v] += ' ';
    vals[v] = round_number(vals[v], 10);//parseFloat(vals[v].substr(0, (vals[v].indexOf('.') + 16)), 10);
    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += (vals[v]+'<br/>');
}
tot = vals[0] + vals[1] + vals[2] + vals[3];
//tot += ' ';
//tot = tot.substr(0, (tot.indexOf('.') + 11));
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += (tot+'<br/>');
```

---

This cuts off any decimal without rounding.

JS:

```
var value1 = 16658807.49;
var newVal = (value1 / 112269423.46428402144)*100;
newVal = newVal + ' ';
newVal = newVal.substr(0, newVal.indexOf('.'));
```

This drops only the decimal point itself.

JS:

```
var value1 = 16658807.49;
var newVal = (value1 / 112269423.46428402144)*100;
newVal = newVal + ' ';
var newVal_1 = newVal.substr(0, newVal.indexOf('.'));
var newVal_2 = newVal.substr((newVal.indexOf('.')+1));
newVal = newVal_1 + newVal_2;
```

To return your stringed number `newVal` to its integer format, use:

```
newVal = parseInt(newVal ,10);
```

Comment: sorry, i do not understand how this is supposed to help me.

Comment: "but, i need to display the percentage as integer (dropping the decimal point)"...somehow I thought this was what you wanted-to drop the decimal. Were you wanting a function to round the number?

Comment: dropping the decimal point is not the issue. making the sum of percentages match 100% is the issue.

Comment: i made a jsfiddle with your answer, can you explain how this helps me? http://jsfiddle.net/dnuxrn8n/6/

Comment: This is still not the desired outcome. The desired outcome would be `10%` `15%` `25%` `50%` = 100% no decimals

Comment: Well, then try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/yq6ycyhr/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/yq6ycyhr/1/) You've about run me to the end of my knowledge. The trouble, in my opinion, is that a number like `0.05...` will round to 0%. Is that what you want?

Comment: this is exactly what i needed for the percent. but what about the original values?

Comment: well, to preserve those, I would just throw the originals in an array before you round them. Then you can call them from that array later.

Comment: you didnt get me on the last one. i need to round the original values in the same way and display them as millions.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yq6ycyhr/2/)? *please say yes, please say yes* lol